# Casperjs can't load data in a div

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs

I am working on a script using casperjs for lesfurets.com, first I click on button 'Choisir votre véhicule' 
link: lesfurets.com/assurance-auto/auto-devis?reset#Vehicule (click on "Par marque/modèle" to show button)

then a div panel(class="MarqueAutoTable") containing marques is showing

[div containing marques](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO8KB.png)

but when I click on marque CITROEN the page doesn't load data containing models in the div(id="modele-panel") related to selected marque using casperjs(in browser it works good), so the page is blocked in the div panel containing marques.

[div containing models related to selected marque](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkost.png)

html code:

-button "Choisir votre véhicule":

```
<div class="field"><div class="field-selection-vehicule" id="VEH_DTL_SELECTION_MODELE"><div class="field-question"><div class="gwt-Label field-label">Modèle du véhicule à assurer :</div></div><div class="field-component"><button type="button" class="gwt-Button button-choix-vehicule principal-cta icon-lesfurets icon-arrow-right after" id="choisir-vehicule" tabindex="12">Choisir votre véhicule</button><span class="gwt-InlineLabel field-selection-vehicule-aucun-modele">Aucun véhicule sélectionné</span></div></div></div>
```

-div panels that will contain models and powers for the selected marque:

```
<div class="VehiculeDeckPanel">
     <div class="MarqueAutoTable">
     <div class="logo-marque selected-marque" id="CITROEN"><div         
     class="widget-logo-marque"><img class="gwt-Image" src="">
    </div></div></div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="properties"  
     id="modele-panel"></div></div>
     <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="properties"   
     id="carburant-panel"></div></div>
     <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="properties"  
     id="carrosserie-panel"></div></div>
      <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="properties"  
      id="puissance-panel"></div></div>
    </div>
```

-my casperjs code:

```
    var casper = require('casper').create({

    clientScripts:  [
    ],
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,        // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
        loadPlugins: false         // use these settings
    },

    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.options.waitTimeout = 180000;


var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.on('remote.message', function(message) {
    this.echo(message);
});

casper.start('https://www.lesfurets.com/assurance-auto/auto-devis#Vehicule', function(){
});

/***********Start-script***************/

casper.wait(10000, function(){
    casper.echo('waiting for start page to load');
})

casper.then(function(){
    casper.evaluate(function(){
        var elt = document.querySelector('select[id="VEH_DTL_DEMANDE"]');
        elt.value = 'deja_assure';
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
   casper.click('input#gwt-uid-2');
});

casper.then(function(){
   casper.evaluate(function(){
       var elt = document.querySelector('div[id="VEH_DTL_IMMAT"] select[class="gwt-ListBox monthSelection"]');
       var elt2 = document.querySelector('div[id="VEH_DTL_IMMAT"] select[class="gwt-ListBox yearSelection"]');

       elt.value = '1'
       elt2.value = '2010'
   });
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.evaluate(function(){
        var elt = document.querySelector('div[id="VEH_DTL_ACHAT"] select[class="gwt-ListBox monthSelection"]');
        var elt2 = document.querySelector('div[id="VEH_DTL_ACHAT"] select[class="gwt-ListBox yearSelection"]');

        elt.value = '2'
        elt2.value = '2011'
    });
});

casper.wait(3000, function(){
   casper.click('button#choisir-vehicule');
});

casper.wait(5000, function(){
    casper.capture('testpage.png');
});


casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@class="MarqueAutoTable"]/div[@id="CITROEN"]'), function() {
    casper.click(x('//*[@class="MarqueAutoTable"]/div[@id="CITROEN"]'));
});

casper.wait(10000, function(){
    casper.capture('testpage1.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: thanks Artjom B,  I'm using phantomjs 1.9.8